# KeyListeners for the game doesn't work anymore as soon as I add a chat panel

Tags: chat, panel, game-engine, keylistener

I'm currently integrating a ChatPanel into a MMORPG. The Problem is, despite I change focus, that the GamePanel doesn't recognize KeyEvents anymore when I add the ChatPanel to the Frame.
Could it be, that the TextField in the ChatPanel surpasses the KeyListeners in the GamePanel?

Comment: Please refer to [mcve] when writing a question . can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Its a Focus issue from what i can tell